# WooCommerce - Get (direct) parent categories in last category

Tags: woocommerce, parent-child

I want to display as links, the parent categories (but not the grandfather categories), only when I am viewing the last/deepest category. To be more expressive, when I browse the categories, I have some code that gets the subcategories/children of the current category I am in. The code is this

```
function sub_cats( $args = array() ) { 
    $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => get_queried_object()->taxonomy,
        'parent'   => get_queried_object_id(),
    ]);
    foreach ( $terms as $term) {
        echo '<li>';   
            echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';  
        echo '<li>';   
    }
}
```

Since I reach the last/deepest category/child of each category tree, I get no other categories to display. 
Now I am asked to display as links, only the direct parent categories (not the grandfathers) of the last/deepest category and only then.

What I figured out is, to check if there are children in the current category and if they do, fire up the above code. If not then get the parent category. But here is where I blow it all up because in return I get as results all attributes and categories in my database.

```
//Get current category

$term = get_queried_object();
$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
    'parent'    => $term->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => false
) );

//If this category has children then get me the children
if($children) {    
     $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => get_queried_object()->taxonomy,
        'parent'   => get_queried_object_id(),
    ]);
    foreach ( $terms as $term) {
        echo '<li>';   
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';  
        echo '<li>';   
    }
} else { //ELSE get me only the parent category -> HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    $caterms = get_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($caterms as $category) {
        if($category->parent == 0){
            echo '<li>';   
            echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';  
            echo '<li>';  

        }
    } 
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

This function gets in li tags, all product categories, from the very first/top-level categories, to the very last/bottom-level categories. Then, when you browse to the bottom/deepest categories, you get all same-(last/deepest)level  categories. So, the category tree, does not vanish when you get to those deep/last categories.

```
function sub_cats( $args = array() ) { 
    $term       = get_queried_object(); //get current term
    $children   = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array( //get term children
                'parent'        => $term->term_id,
                'hide_empty'    => false
                ) );

    if($children) {    
        $terms = get_terms(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
                'parent'   => $term->term_id,
            )
        );
        foreach ( $terms as $term) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
                                    }
    } else {
        $term_children = get_terms(
                        'product_cat',
                                array(
                                    'parent' => $term->parent,
                                    )
                                    );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child ) . '">' . $child->name . '</a> 
    </li>';
                                            }
                                    }
        }
}

add_shortcode ('sub_cats', ' sub_cats' );
```

Special thanks to Panos(VG) and @Frits

Answer (score 0):

You could just make use of the `parent` property inside your `term` object and grab the term directly using [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/).

```
$term       = get_queried_object(); //get current term
$children   = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array( //get term children
    'parent'        => $term->term_id,
    'hide_empty'    => false
) );

if($children) {    
    $terms = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
            'parent'   => $term->term_id,
        )
    );
    foreach ( $terms as $term) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
} else {
    $parent_id      = $term->parent;
    $parent_term    = get_term_by('term_id', $parent_id); //get direct parent term
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $parent_id ) . '">' . $parent_term->name . '</a></li>'; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Frits. I tried what you suggested but got -> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in ... functions

Comment: -> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in ... functions  happens only when i get to the last/deepst category. The rest parent category tree is working though.

Comment: @Papasof ah I think I know where the problem was. I had the wrong variables in the echo statement - try now?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I dont get the parent categories of the last child  when i view the last child.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. you really helped me a lot. I managed to get it working with a slight modification. An to be honest I think I misinterpreted my thought and asked wrong question, which you solved. The actual question was how to get all current-same-level subcategories from the direct parent category. I will post my function incase it is helpfull to someone. And again much gratitude Frits

Comment: Ah wonderful @Papasof - happy you managed to fine a resolution :)